# Can I use opentsdb database for vehicle gps data?

Tags: hadoop, gps, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, opentsdb

I having trouble finding out if I can use opentsdb for storing vehicle gps data
eg. vehicleId, timestamp, latitude, longitude

Is opentsdb ideal for this or I should use Hbase. I have seen lot of examples which use hbase for gps data eg. hortonworks examples. But I haven't seen a single example which use opentsdb for gps data.

My question is if we can use opentsdb for gps data, then what will be its table design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenTSDB  is used for analytics data, in your case like this; location, timestamp, number of cars seen in that location. For one vehicle, i think you should use hbase, vehicleid as rowkey (if id is not sequential), a cell in hbase already has timestamp, and lat as column key, long. as column data. Or you can put lat and long to column key and not write anything to column value. Or if you want a query like to get last 10 locations of a particular vehicle, you can make your column key as (Long.MAX_VALUE - timestamp), so they will be ordered, when you select a row(vehicleid) you can just get first 10 Result in Scan results, then close result object.

let me know, if you have any other questions.

---

edit: answer to comments below;

then, you can store data like this,

- rowkey: vehicleid+yyyyMMdd , (all info of a vehicle for a day in same row),
- column key;(Long.MAX_VALUE - timestamp)  for a data time,
- column data: all info in special format, i mean a protobuf object or something like this, it will be stored as byte array and can be auto converted byte[] to object and vice versa by protobuf easily.

OR for column data, you can try this way,

- column key: (Long.MAX_VALUE - timestamp)+loc, (Long.MAX_VALUE - timestamp)+speed, etc..
- column data: lat,long for loc, integer for speed, angle, etc..

This rowkey structure provides you to get last data points easy and ordered, column data structure is not so important, depends on how you want to write your code.

Comment: Let's say if I receive location data from thousands of vehicles. In my case timestamp also comes in data packet along with lat and long. Now I need to store all data from different vehicles. In this case will the design given by you change (i.e will I be still using hbase? Or OpenTSDB). Isn't data we have is time series data?

Comment: I forgot to mention other sensor parameters which I am getting i.e speed of vehicle, turn angle etc. Will these parameters change the design of schema?

Comment: Yes, speed and other data can change your data design. Hbase is good for finding one vehicle's data in millions of vehicles, that is not the issue. I think it depends how you want to read data from hbase, i mean, do you want to get it seperately for speed, location, angle ,etc, for drawing a chart for speed for example. OR since your data comes in package, and you may want show vehicle's all info on map or something and every timestamp can be a point on map, when user clicks a point, you show speed, loc, angle, etc at the same time.

Comment: Yes I need to get all the info of vehicle. Eg. we will be having queries like :
1. What are last 20 location of vehicle?
2. What is the speed or other info of vehicle at any given date time?
3. How vehicle travelled between given time t1 and t2?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more questions, I can do queries on hive like this- Where vehicle has stop in last 2 days? How much miles it drove in last day etc etc.

Comment: Hive ? We were talking about hbase :) I dont know about hive as much as hbase but, since it gives you a sql like query language, you can do select distinct query for which locations and sum query for how many miles it travelled. But if you want to do these in hbase way, you will need that time period data in your applications memory and calculate necessary metrics yourself.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I meant hbase not hive :). Well thanks for your help